# Cannot call methods on char

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

This error seems to be coming from the following block of code. what is the possible cause of this error?

> Cannot call method on char

```
INSERT INTO #ActiveTerminals
SELECT DISTINCT a.TerminalId, SerialNumber, a.[LoadTime] [LastSale] 
FROM Terminal INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Ticket.TerminalId,max(LoadTime) [LoadTime] FROM 
    Ticket with (NOLOCK)
    JOIN ProductDenomination with (NOLOCK) ON (ProductDenomination.DenominationId = Ticket.DenominationId)
    WHERE ProductDenomination.ProductId NOT IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@sExcludedProducts)) AND
     datediff(day,LoadTime,@dteActiveSalesEndDate) <= @iLastSoldWithinDays
    GROUP BY TerminalId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT VarTicket.TerminalId, max(TransactionDate) [LoadTime]  FROM 
    VarTicket with (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE VarTicket.ProductId NOT IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@sExcludedProducts)) AND
     VarTicket.TerminalId NOT IN (SELECT TerminalId FROM #ActiveTerminals)
    AND datediff(day,TransactionDate,@dteActiveSalesEndDate) <= @iLastSoldWithinDays
    GROUP BY TerminalId
)a ON (Terminal.TerminalId = a.TerminalId.TerminalId) 
ORDER BY a.TerminalId, SerialNumber
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the error?

Comment: @JustinNiessner - the error is in the title, can you focus us on a line? can you show the values and declaration of the parameters? can you show the code of your function (`fn_MVParam`)?

Comment: @JustinNiessner the error is "Cannot call methods on char"

Comment: @p.campbell yes is does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this line:

```
)a ON (Terminal.TerminalId = a.TerminalId.TerminalId)
```

change it to this:

```
)a ON (Terminal.TerminalId = a.TerminalId)
```

Comment: :| **faceSlap** ... I should be hit for six (cricket) or in baseball, hit for home run.

Comment: @Nation It's a common typo and hard to see.  The key was knowing that that error almost always comes from an extra (`.`) somewhere.

Comment: If it helps anyone... my mistake was putting a period instead comma before an additional column I had added to the select.

Comment: Would be really nice if this were picked up by the parser instead

Comment: @raven It would be really difficult for the parser to do that because there are legitimate cases where two or even three periods could appear in a reference at that point. That means that it technically isn't a syntax error (which is why it isn't called out as one) and thus cannot be raised by the parser, but rather a semantic error that can only be detected when it is actually compiled (and finds that there is no method on `a.TerminalId` with that name).